# Entanglement up to a finite distance

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

We do not have a theory which predicts the working distance of entanglement, and this distance is usually taken to be infinity. However, up to now, experiments have just rigorously confirmed entanglement over several kilometers. Is there any attempt with the assumption that this distance is finite?

Comment: What's the max. distance up to which conditional probability "works"?

Comment: Entanglement has nothing to do with a distance. The starting conditions for entangled particles are responsible for the state, we get, then measuring them. It is the artful work of people to exclude the influence from the environment, which destroys the entanglement quickly.

Comment: If you mean experimental games with that, quantum teleportation has been verified at 143 kilometers, see e.g. http://phys.org/news/2012-09-km-physicists-quantum-teleportation-distance.html - Maybe the record was beaten since that time. At any rate, no expert doubts that entanglement is able to fully sustain itself at least up to the radius of the visible Universe.

Comment: In the spirit of Luboš Motl's comment, there is probably very little (except for money, that is) in the way of combining an entanglement experiment with lunar laser ranging to verify that entanglement can be sustained over more than half a million kilometers. It's a useless experiment, of course, but something like it could be done, for sure.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, from the point of view of conditional probability, there is no reason to doubt the distance, although the fact of teleportation is a little confusing.

Comment: Quantum teleportation transports information, not matter. If you think your radio, tv and computer network are magic, then quantum teleportation might be magic, too. If you think you understand how they work, then you shouldn't be too surprised about quantum teleportation, either, it's the same thing using a quantum effect.